# Jquery use any select box ID starting with

Tags: jquery, select

I cannot seem to get this to work, as you see my code below requires that a select box with the first part called "#select_" and will then end in random number ie "#select_123", so I need to use a wild card. But the `[id^='select_']` seems to be not correct.

I also need to pass the select elements "selected" option to a variable.

```
jQuery("[id^='select_']").change(function() {

var optionValueText = jQuery.trim(jQuery($("[id^='select_']")+' :selected').text());

   //do something  

});
```

I know this code works fine if I just card code the id name ie jQuery("#select_123") but I do not have that option.

Comment: If these select boxes are similar, couldn't you just decorate them with a class?

Comment: This sounds like a wrong way to do what you are after. Better use data-* values or classes.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the ["Starts With" selector :](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) like this

```
$('div[id^="select_"] :selected')
```

**Starts With Selector** :

*`Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value beginning exactly with a given string.`*

Answer (score 0):

You can try to make the select generic and then check the id as they change:

```
$("select").change(function(){

  var n=$(this).attr("id").split("_");
  if(n == "select")
  {
   //do something here
  }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZTMKK/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this part:

```
$("[id^='select_']")+' :selected'
```

You're attempting to concatenate a jQuery object with a string, which would work but result in an invalid selector.

You can simply use:

```
'[id^="select_"] :selected'
```

Or, since you already have a reference to the specific `<select>` element, change the entire thing to this:

```
jQuery("[id^='select_']").change(function() {
    var optionValueText = jQuery.trim(jQuery(':selected', this).text());
    //do something  
});
```